# Monster Spells per day

Tags: spells, monsters

I was just looking up the Barlgura and stumbled on the 1/day casts for entangle, phantasmal force. Does that mean that once per day it is able to cast either spell (like a spell slot it can use once for either spell) or is it able to cast both spells once per day?

Comment: Welcome to RPGSE! Please add a system-and-edition tag to your question.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't know how to add a tag yet (by using the [edit] option), you can also tell us in a comment what you are playing and we can help with adding the right tag.

Comment: Could you please say us which game are you using? I think you are using D&D 5e, but we need your confirmation.

Answer (score -2):

Whoopsy. Figured it out. For anyone wondering it is 1/day each. I should learn to read before asking questions.